# Algebra simplification of transfer function, help please!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I ran into problems trying to simplify this:

*Given*
$$ H(s)=\frac{0.9661s^4}{s^4+8.824S^3+44.86s^{2}+105.6s+254.2} $$

now subsitute $s=(\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})$ into $H(s)$ to get $G(z)$:

$$ G(z) = \frac{0.9661(\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})}{(\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})^{4}+8.824(\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})^{3}+44.86(\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})^{2}+105.6(\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}})+254.2}$$

It's for a signal theory problem where a transformation is performed to get the digital transfer function from the s-domain, the answer according to my guide is:

$$G(z) = \frac{0.003-0.012z^{-1}+0.018z^{-2}-0.012z^{-3}+0.003z^{-4}}{1+2.808z^{-1}+3.294z^{-2}+1.1857z^{-3}+0.421z^{-4}}$$

But for the life of me I can't seem to get the same values, I also tried coding a simple MatLab program using the expand function but it doesn't return the answer in the form I need it to be.

Help would be SO greatly appreciated, especially if someone can advise what to do in Matlab!

Comment: I've seen fun stuff, but this has nothing to do with it :) That said, I will write an answer shortly

Comment: Please check your equations. In the first equation there is no coefficient 44.86, but in the latter there is. What is the correct coefficient for $s^2$? Also, you forgot to raise $s$ to the corresponding powers in the second equation.

Comment: Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, starting with the function
$$ H(s)=\frac{0.9661s^4}{s^4+8.824S^3+44.86s^2+105.6s+254.2} $$

we want to substitute $s=\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$.
Now (finger crossed)
\begin{align*}H(z)&=\frac{0.9661\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^4}{\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^4+8.824\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^3+44.86\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2+105.6\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)+254.2}\\
&=\frac{0.9661(z-1)^4}{(z-1)^4+8.824(z-1)^3(z+1)+44.86(z-1)^2(z+1)^2+105.6(z-1)(z+1)^3+254.2(z+1)^4}\\
&= \frac{0.00233085 z^4 - 0.0093234 z^3 + 0.0139851 z^2 - 0.0093234 z + 0.00233085}{z^4 + 2.91049 z^3 + 3.47777 z^2 + 1.97655 z + 0.447873}\\
&= \frac{0.00233085  - 0.0093234 z^{-1} + 0.0139851 z^{-2} - 0.0093234 z^{-3} + 0.00233085z^{-4}}{1 + 2.91049 z^{-1} + 3.47777 z^{-2} + 1.97655 z^{-3} + 0.447873z^{-4}}
\end{align*}
where I've used [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B0.9661(z-1)%5E4%7D%7B(z-1)%5E4%2B8.824(z-1)%5E3(z%2B1)%2B44.86(z-1)%5E2(z%2B1)%5E2%2B105.6(z-1)(z%2B1)%5E3%2B254.2(z%2B1)%5E4%7D) in the third step.

(I honestly don't know what this exercise is about, but it makes no sense to me computing this by hand)

Comment: I've managed to get the same coefficients from Matlab as well, thank you so much!